# How do we formally say that a function is non-strict in an argument?

Tags: haskell

We say that a function is strict in its argument if

```
f ⊥ = ⊥
```

but how do we say that a function is non-strict in its argument? Can we say that a function is non-strict if

```
f ⊥ ≠ ⊥
```

?

How does that extend to functions of many arguments, where we might or might not evaluate an argument depending on the value of some other argument?

I'm asking this in the context of better documenting the strictness properties of Haskell functions using Haddock documentation.

Comment: You are correct, a function is non-strict if f ⊥ ≠ ⊥.  If you might not evaluate an argument depending on <condition>, the function is non-strict (in the argument that might not be evaluated).

Comment: If a function *always* evaluates its argument, it is called strict in that argument. A function that *never* evaluates an argument is called uninteresting in that argument. OK, OK, I've just made it up. But studying this trivial behaviour doesn't seem to be very exciting science. A function that does *not always* evaluate its argument is called non-strict in that argument.

Comment: @n.m. A function can completely ignore its argument and still be strict in that argument.

Comment: Given this it seems to me that saying that a function is lazy in an argument isn't very interesting, as that statement lacks enough precision for the caller to make use of that fact. The caller needs know under which conditions the argument is evaluated to be able to rely on laziness for some correctness purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no standard notation for expressing complex strictness properties.  It's also no not as simple as just being strict, since for data structures you may need to say exactly how much gets evaluated.

That said, for a simple function like

```
cond c t e = if c then t else e
```

you can imagine saying that the strictness is `1 & (2 | 3)`, meaning that it will evaluate the first argument, and either the second or the third.  These are the kind of strictness properties that a simple strictness analyzer will come up with.  (And simple ones seem to be the only ones that are worth while.)